# Restricting MySQL 3306 port with IPTABLES

Tags: mysql, security, centos, firewall, iptables

How to block mysql port 3306 for everybody, but allow it for a specific IP? This is what I currently do:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need multiple rules to do that.
In most cases, what will happen with a connection depends on the first rule, which it matches. So, first we accept our friends connection, second, we drop anybody other. Voila!

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 2 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
```

Comment: i dont need make rules for Localhost? how about udp ?

Comment: From localhost you are connecting from unix sockets, which hasn't anything with mysql to do. But if you need this, you should accept 127.0.0.1 as well. Udp gasn't anything with mysql to do, it goes with tcp only.

Comment: Fix to my previous comment: from localhost you are talking on unix sockets and not on TCP sockets. Unix sockets are completely independent from the iptables. In the case of the unix sockets, access control can be get by file-system level permissions. | MySQL doesn't communicate on UDP. | You can also connect mysql with TCP on the localhost, in this case you have to contact 127.0.0.1 on TCP (and tune your iptables rules as you wish - the local connections will be connections from 127.0.0.1).