# Securing a simple Linux server that holds a MySQL database?

Tags: linux, security, ubuntu

A beginner question, but I've looked through many questions on this site and haven't found a simple, straightforward answer:

I'm setting up a Linux server running Ubuntu to store a MySQL database.

It's important this server is secure as possible, as far as I'm aware my main concerns should be incoming DoS/DDoS attacks and unauthorized access to the server itself.

The database server only receives incoming data from one specific IP (101.432.XX.XX), on port 3000. I only want this server to be able to receive incoming requests from this IP, as well as prevent the server from making any outgoing requests.

I'd like to know:

1. What is the best way to prevent my database server from making outgoing requests and receiving incoming requests solely from 101.432.XX.XX? Would closing all ports ex. 3000 be helpful in achieving this?
2. Are there any other additions to the linux environment that can boost security?
   I've taken very basic steps to secure my phpmyadmin portal (linked to the MySQL database), such as restricting access to solely my personal IP address.

To access the database server requires the SSH key (which itself is password protected).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A famous man once said "[security is a process, not a product](https://www.schneier.com/crypto-gram/archives/2000/0515.html)."

So you have a db server that should ONLY listen to one other server for db connections and you have the specific IP for that one other server. There are several layers of restriction you can put in place to accomplish this

**1) Firewall**

If your MySQL server is fortunate enough to be behind a firewall, you should be able to block out all connections by default and allow only certain connections on certain ports. I'm not sure how you've set up your db server, or whether the *other* server that wants to access it is on the same LAN or not or whether both machines are just virtual machines. It all depends on where your server is running and what kind of firewall you have, if any.

I often set up servers on Amazon Web Services. They offer security groups that allow you to block all ports by default and then allow access on *specific ports* from *specific IP blocks* using CIDR notation.  I.e., you grant access in port/IP combination pairs. To let your one server get through, you might allow access on port 3000 to IP address 101.432.xx.xx.

The details will vary depending on your architecture and service provider.

**2) IPTables**

Linux machines can run a local firewall (i.e., a process that runs on each of your servers itself) called iptables. This is some powerful stuff and it's easy to lock yourself out. There's a brief post [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309726/restricting-mysql-3306-port-with-iptables) but you have to be careful. It's easy to lock yourself out of your server using IPtables.Keep in mind that you need to permit access on port 22 for all of your servers so that you can login to them. If you can't connect on port 22, you'll never be able to login using ssh again. I always try to take a snapshot of a machine before tinkering with iptables lest I permanently lock myself out.

There is a bit of info [here](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/restricting-mysql-port-access) about iptables and MySQL also.

**3) MySQL cnf file**

MySQL has some configuration options that can limit any db connections to localhost only - i.e., you can prevent any remote machines from connecting. I don't know offhand if any of these options can limit the remote machines by IP address, but it's worth a look.

**4) MySQL access control via GRANT, etc.**

MySQL allows you [very fine-grained control](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connection-access.html) over who can access what in your system. Ideally, you would grant access to information or functions only on a need-to-know basis. In practice, this can be a hassle, but if security is what you want, you'll go the extra mile.

To answer your questions:

1) YES, you should definitely try and limit access to your DB server's MySQL port 3000 -- and also port 22 which is what you use to connect via SSH.

2) Aside from ones mentioned above, your limiting of PHPMyAdmin to only your IP address sounds really smart -- *but make sure you don't lock yourself out accidentally*. I would also strongly suggest that you disable password access for ssh connections, forcing the use of key-pairs instead.You can find [lots of examples on google](https://www.google.com/#q=ssh+turn+off+password+auth%2C+force+key+pairs).

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to prevent my database server from making outgoing requests and receiving incoming requests solely from 101.432.XX.XX? Would closing all ports ex. 3000 be helpful in achieving this?

If you don't have access to a separate firewall, I would use ip tables. There are a number of managers available for you on this. So yes. Remember that if you are using IPtables, make sure you have a way of accessing the server via OOB (short for out of band, which means accessing it in such a way that if you make a mistake in IP tables, you can still access it via console/remote hands/IPMI, etc)

Next up, when creating users, you should only allow that subnet range plus user/pass authentication.

> Are there any other additions to the linux environment that can boost security? I've taken very basic steps to secure my phpmyadmin portal (linked to the MySQL database), such as restricting access to solely my personal IP address.

[Ubuntu ships with something called AppArmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor). I would investigate that. That can be helpful to prevent some shenanigans. An alternative is SELinux.

Further, take more steps with phpmyadmin. That is your weakest link in the security tool chain we are building.

> To access the database server requires the SSH key (which itself is password protected).

If security is a concern, I would **NOT** use SSH key style access. Instead, I would use [MySQLs native support for SSL certificate authentication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html). [Here is now to configure it with phpmyadmin.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssl-certificates-with-phpmyadmin-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps)